# My program is duplicating the input stream from a textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

So, I am a newbie in C# and I have this listbox in my program that is duplicating the contents that it's reading from a textbox. 
Whenever I start my program, it loads the contents of the save.txt file to the listbox, but when it does that, it loads a duplicate of all the save.txt content. I tried clearing the listbox before loading the contents but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
    private void readList()
    {
        string line;
        listBox.Items.Clear(); //I tried to clear the listbox but it's not working
        listBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Paul.DESKTOP-HGGDG1D\Desktop\My C# apps\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\bin\Debug\save.txt"));
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("save.txt"))
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(line);
            }
    }

    public myAgenda()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        readList(); 
    }

    private void add_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(add_txt.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Please enter a value");
        }
        else
        {
            holder = add_txt.Text;
            listBox.Items.Add(ctr + " " + holder);
            ctr++;
            add_txt.Text = " ";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string sPath = "save.txt";
        System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
        foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
        }
        SaveFile.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: is it duplicating the whole stream again or duplicate entries in the save.txt which are just getting populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling `listbox` two time in `readlist` method i.e.

First Time :

```
  listBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Paul.DESKTOP-HGGDG1D\Desktop\My C# apps\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\bin\Debug\save.txt"));
```

Second Time :

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("save.txt"))
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(line);
        }
```

You can remove either of one approach to fill up the content. First approach is better to use for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the content twice on your listBox.

Try to do this:

```
private void readList()
{
    string line;
    listBox.Items.Clear(); 

    //Comment out this line then put the File Directory on the StreamReader
    //listBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Paul.DESKTOP-HGGDG1D\Desktop\My C# apps\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\bin\Debug\save.txt"));

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Paul.DESKTOP-HGGDG1D\Desktop\My C# apps\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\MyAgenda\bin\Debug\save.txt"))
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(line);
        }
}
```